# twitter app - how does it know when a link is an image?

Tags: twitter

In both the iPhone and Mac Twitter app, if you click on a link and its an image, it opens the image up in a special window. How is this done internally? How does it know that that link points to an image?

Do they search for file endings and work it out from there? I thought it maybe a field in the API feed, but can't find anything?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it will check for the [Content-Type header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) which gives the MIME-type of the data in the body, such as text/html,image/gif,application/rss etc, then if it is an image type, then opens it in a special window.